# language discrimination in Q&A

Tags: support, vandalism

In a post during question I see that person has not-so-good english and he's russian. I'm answering on russian to provide a help that is suitable defenately better to a person who is in need and now my answer and thread is deleted due to a reason "stick to english". Thhis IS not good and it's a racism due to the language. I'm well-aware of the fact that the *primary* language is english, but I'll translate my answer when it's fixed(it's not yet). The question is here https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12951/tor-does-not-start

Please, i DO respect the site rules, but please respect people - especially question askers with an english skill problem -  in return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such a situation, in my opinion, the best to do is to write your message in English, with a translation in Russian.
And this way, no deletion.

Because you call it "racism", but you prevent people who don't speak Russian to understand your message, so they could consider it as "racist" the same way. You have to consider the Russian person who is not very good at English, and the English speaking users the same way.
If it was really racist (but is Russian language a race?), they would delete everything in another language, if you write in both, I'm almost sure they won't delete it.

Comment: good point! Thanks for the clarification - and I agree with your arguments. I was writing in russian because - sadly - knowing foreign languages even on a fair-communication leve is a very rare thing

Comment: It's hard not being a native speaker in an English word, I know that ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution to this is to provide the answer in English, this can then easily be translated to most languages with a translator when needed.

To call it racist is harsh, it's more about how to communicate so that most people using the site can understand the questions and answers.

As you already mention - the site is primarily English, and also the author of that question also wrote it in English, so I feel it's safe to assume he would also understand a answer in English, or be able to use a translator.

Comment: Author's mistakes in English are obvious, and his english is "not so good" - it's a common problem in Russian Federation, sadly. So that's why I was answering in the way that will provide a better reach for an asker's understanding. Now when my answer was deleted I think he's hardly coming back

Comment: If the English is bad then users can suggest edits to improve the post, this will also help the author of the post.